# Object Focus problem with Safari and Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, safari

I have the following javascript being called to request a focus when page is loaded.

This code works 100% OK with Firefox and IE7, but Chrome and Safari do not seem to move the focus at all. How to make it work with all browsers?

```
 document.getElementById("MyFlashFile").focus();
```

Comment: This is still not working in the current build of Chrome for Windows (Version 28.0.1500.72 m) none of the provided workarounds work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure this code is being called after the **entire** page has been rendered. It's probably being called above the HTML it refers to, so the element will not exist yet.

Various JavaScript frameworks have utilities to tell you when the [DOM is ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24(document).ready()).

Answer (score 16):

It took me hours searching the Internet, but finally I found a solution that works on the lastest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
The following code solves the problem for good:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
  <script>
    function setFocusOnFlash() {
      var f=swfobject.getObjectById('myFlashObjectId');
      if (f) { f.tabIndex = 0; f.focus(); }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="setFocusOnFlash()">
```

This example assumes the flash is embedded using the SWFObject library. If not, you should set the f variable to the Object or Embed tag which holds the flash movie.

**Edited on 5 May 2012**: Well, unfortunately it seems that the `tabIndex` workaround no longer works for all combinations of browser (Chrome/Safari) and operating system.
For instance, currently Chrome 18 on Windows fails.

See the link below, provided by *Christian Junk*, to get the status of the problem's resolution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What is the ID specified for getObjectById()? The ID provided to swfObject via attributes.id or second argument of the swfobject.embedSWF() call?

Comment: Silva

Your solution is amazing!  I have been looking for a solution to this problem for MONTHS.  Finally, I found it.  Thanks for the post.  

-Chris

Comment: Also not working for me. As a test, I tried putting an alert in the `if` statement. The alert does show, but the flash is not focused. I also tried creating a simple page with just a text box (no flash), and setting focus to that text box, which DID work there, but not for the flash page. I also tried using `document.getElementById` instead of `swfobject.getObjectById`, which still had the same result. So it looks like there is something else wrong, since we know the `focus()` function DOES work and IS being called. This all works with IE and FF, but not for Chrome or Safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: As @Tim TJey Jun mentioned below, to get it to work in Chrome 12, you need to add `params.wmode = "opaque";`. For me, this made it start working perfectly in Chrome and IE, but then FF and Safari are worse than ever. Now, you can't type ANYTHING, regardless of whether or not you click on the text field. I suppose I could do a browser check to only set that parameter for Chrome, but I would really like a better solution if anyone has one.

Comment: I placed the code like that and it gives flash focus, but doesn´t gives keyboard focus.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to ensure that you can set focus to a flash file that works in all browsers. IE and Firefox have solved this problem (for the most part), but Chrome and Safari are both based off of Webkit which does not have a solution.

If you ever notice on YouTube or other video / flash site that the first thing you see is something to entice you to click on the player, that is due to this problem.

One developer came up with a clever workaround, but it does involve adding some ActionScript  to your flash file, this can be a pain in the ass if you are building a generic player.

Gary Bishop: [Fixing Firefox Flash Foolishness](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~gb/wp/blog/2007/06/08/fixing-firefox-flash-foolishness/)

Another sort of solution is to set your wmode to opaque. I've heard this works in some situations, but will screw up cursors in text areas. I haven't had much luck with this either, but you can give it a shot.

You can find more information about the no focus bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93149).

Comment: Adam, check Cláudio Silva's solution below. It worked for me :).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is a bug in Chrome:

"window.document.getElementById('swfID').focus() not working for flash objects"

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27868

I've tried to find a workaround but I was not able to find one ;(

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Cláudio Silva answer , you need to set `wmode="opaque"`