# Passing focus to Silverlight/Flash object in Chrome and Safari

Tags: flash, silverlight, safari, google-chrome, webkit

There is a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27868) with Safari and Chrome, when you can't pass a focus to plugin (Flash or Silverlight). There is also [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594821/object-focus-problem-with-safari-and-chrome-browsers) at SO that asks how to solve it (marked as answered, though technically it's not the answer).

I'm really concerned with this situation, since it totally breaks user experience [image]
. Do you know somebody who develops Webkit? What can we do? Post a comment [on this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27868)? Write a fix? Convince users to switch to FF?

[image: Please, help.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new post made by me here at SO on the page you mentioned above. It should really solve the problem.

It seems Chrome and Safari do not allow the flash object to be focused because, by default, it has no value defined for the tabIndex property and, as such, takes no part in the tab chain.

Comment: OH MY GOD! You made my day, Cláudio! Your solution does work! Thank you very-very-very much! For the history, could you please edit your answer here and paste your life-saver snippet with setting tabIndex?