# Keyboard focus being stolen by Flash

Tags: flash, keyboard, focus

Performing a search, I noticed several questions dedicated to how to steal/trap the keyboard focus of the visitor. Considering this site is dedicated to programming that's not suprising. I was wondering if anyone can advise me on how to prevent this type of behavior. Losing keyboard focus to flash basically removes my browser's functionality until I use the mouse to click elsewhere (I use Mozilla Firefox). Anyone know of some kind of plugin or greasemonkey script that will prevent my keyboard focus from being stolen? Normal browser "shortcuts" are rendered useless by having to use the mouse to return keyboard focus to the browser.

Edit: Reply to the post below, I do have flashblock / noscript and some other things. My issue is flash that I want to see/interact with stealing my focus. Basically looking for something I can toggle that will prevent flash from getting keyboard focus or a way to force my firefox keyboard commands to the browser

Comment: HELP! Mee Too! Drives me batty as I am heavily keyboard driven.

Comment: The OP is not looking to program something, they are looking for a plugin.  This belongs on superuser.

Comment: migrate to superuser please!
install [Focus Retainer addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/focus-regainer/) and press `ctrl`+`f12`

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, it is almost a decade old [well known FF bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78414) (and now in Chrome too), which is not present in IE. All the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> etc. keys just stop working when the focus is on a flash object.

The worse thing is, no one seems to know the fix for it yet (see the thread above). Some IBM people made a [hack fix for Linux](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-78414-firefox-flash/index.html), but there is none for Windows. It is really really annoying.

[update Mar 2013: In google chrome Version "24.0.1312.52 m" and I assume higher versions, the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key does not loose focus to flash]

Comment: I got this horrible hack working in Chrome with jQuery, where `this` is some element of the page we're fine if the viewport scrolls to: $("<input>").css({opacity: 0}).appendTo(this).focus().remove();

Comment: cool, this really works!!! Thanks Henrik, it must be the correct answer and not a comment

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> combination that would release the focus. The only ones working are that of operation system's. It does not help you to go to another window, the focus still stays, and no, you can not change tab, close it or do anything else either you normally would with keyboard.

I was using my computer without a mouse for a while and this was the first actual problem I had (in addition to missing drag'n'drop features for some sites and facing unreachable button like icons). So those of you who face the same dilemma and don't wish to close the Firefox altogether, you can still use <kbd>ALT</kbd> to focus on toolbar of the application (at least in Windows). However, there is no option for closing the tab but you can select any other site from History (e.g. your home page which comes first with h letter) and then finally close the tab.

So (at least in Windows using <kbd>FF5</kbd>) e.g. in English version of Firefox you could type:
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
and then go back using <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (or close the tab with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

Similar question:
[Flash steals browser focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254111/flash-steals-browser-focus)

The (not accepted but looks promising) answer of:

```
 document.body.focus();
```

may work for you. That can easily be greasemonkeyed. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX 10.6 using Firefox 4, if the plugin (flash) has focus and your tabbing does not work by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a new tab, etc..

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> first to give the browser address bar focus, and then do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Alt-Tabbing** to your current app will return focus.

Comment: In a browser running multiple tabs this does not move focus from flash content when you return to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to make sure you are using a flash player higher than version 6.0.  Also, another responder was correct.  FireFox should not automatically take focus of inline flash content...it isn't designed that way.

Secondly, This is not just an annoyance, this is an accessibility concern.  Those users who can only navigate with a keyboard or assistive device like a screen reader will not be able to escape...because they don't/cant't use a mouse.

To avoid flash in keyboard navigation, or to hide unimportant Flash content from both web browser and screen readers, add the wmode option with a value of opaque to both the object and embed tags of the web page containing the Flash movie or swf.

Example of code:

```
<object ...>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<embed wmode="opaque" ...>
</embed>
</object>
```

This will effectively hide the Flash movie from the screen reader/assistive device and the keyboard. It will still appear visibly within the page, but while navigating through the page, the keyboard will bypass the Flash content and the screen reader will act as if it isn't even there.

HOWEVER!!!!
If the movie/swf DOES contain important information, either display the Flash movie in a page by itself or include the link to download the latest version of the Flash player and inform users that they need to use this version. -- Of course, you should then make your flash piece keyboard navigable.

DOWNFALL OF FLASH:  Natively keyboard navigable flash is ONLY -- I repeat ONLY available in Internet Explorer...BECAUSE Adobe/Macromedia designed "Accessible Flash" to work with MSAA (Microsoft Active Accessibility) technology and the only browser that supports MSAA technology is Internet Explorer.